# Send Image file with Google reCaptcha v2 token to PHP via jQuery + Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, recaptcha

I want to POST and upload image via AJAX with Google reCaptcha v2 validation. but I am facing an issue that I am not not able to send image with caption text with google recaptcha token in Ajax. I coded two function as I know but both was not working. The function I made is the code snippet.

Please help me how I send Image with text in Ajax with reCaptcha token in PHP / jQuery/ AJAX.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("form#addbanner").unbind("submit").bind("submit", function(e) {
        //debugger; 
        e.preventDefault();
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
          grecaptcha.execute('MY_RECAPTCHA_CODE', {
            action: 'add_web_banner'
          }).then(function(token) {
            /*let formData = {
              imagehere : $('input[name="imagehere"]').val(),
              bannertitle : $('input[name="bannertitle"]').val(),
              action : 'add_web_banner',
              type: 'add_web_banner'
            };*/ //not working

            /*let formData = {
              var formData = new FormData($("form#addWeb-Banner")[0]);
              formData.append('token': token);
            };*/ //not working 

            //*POST Image sent in (binary way), I dont want to use JSON in types*//

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              data: formData,
              cache: false,
              success: function(response) {
                hide_loader();
                if (response.status == "success") {
                  $("form#addWeb-Banner")[0].reset();
                  alert("Great");
                } else {
                  alert("Ops!");
                }
              },
            });
          });
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="bs-example form-horizontal AddWebBanner" id="addbanner" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Upload Image</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <input type="file" class="form-control" title="Upload Photo" id="BannerImage" name="imagehere" accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Caption of Banner</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" title="Caption of Banner" name="bannertitle" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right" id="addBannerBtn">POST</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML and formData to the following

Give an id selector your caption banner.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="caption_banner" title="Caption of Banner" name="bannertitle" />
```

Store using the [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) like this and then sent formData via `ajax`

```
var formData = new FormData();

//Append Image
formData.append('file', $('#BannerImage')[0].files[0]);

//Append banner caption
formData.append('caption', $('#caption_banner').val());
```

You can also use jQuery [.serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method to send data to your backend via ajax

```
var formData = $('form#addbanner').serialize()
```

Answer (score 1):

thank for @AlwaysHelping but there was one mistake but I has been fix that..below are the correct answer for future user troubles..
I not mentioned `processData: false, contentType: false,` in ajax.. so the final code will be..

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#BannerImage')[0].files[0]);
formData.append('caption', $('#caption_banner').val());

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function (response) { ... }
```

peace :)

Comment: we can assume , I though everyone know about that .. how to code reCaptcha v2 with this.. so I don't think to edit that script..

Comment: @Shubham Glad that i could helped you. Thank you.